# Inserting a \bigskip between section and subsection using a macro?

Tags: macros, spacing, sectioning

I'm trying to conform to the IoP guidelines, which from the IoP latex files they provide do not seem to follow the IoP guidelines. Several colleagues of mine have altered the files so they do fit the guidelines, with the caveat of needing to place `\bigskip{}` between section and subsection where one immediately follows the other.

Is it possible to automate this with a macro, so I don't need to go through my document and manually insert/remember to insert one?

I'm already using a macro as such:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
```

Do I follow that formatting? How is it done?

Comment: It's quite difficult to answer without knowing the context: what's the class used?

Comment: iopart.cls ? I'm assuming that's the class file.

Comment: The {spacing} tag *is* appropriate.

Comment: @lockstep Sorry I misunderstood the edits that had been done, and I thought the macro tag had been taken out. Is it clear what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You wanted to re-add the (somewhat appropriate) {macros} tag.

Comment: @lockstep I meant 'Is it clear what I'm trying to do *in my question*?'

Comment: I think so. :-)

Comment: @lockstep So it's just know one know how/wants to help?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think your question has no obvious, easy answer.

Comment: @lockstep Really? I thought making macros would be pretty easy. Nevermind.

Comment: It's fairly easy to add`\bigskip` after eyery `\section`. It's not that easy to add `\bigskip` only if a `\subsection` follows.

Comment: Could you add a `\bigskip{}` before every subsection?

Comment: @egreg is it easier now?

Comment: No. One *might* add code to `\section` to see whether a `\subsection` follows directly. But from what I see in the result of the typesetting this seems not to be necessary.

Comment: @egreg Meaning it is already done in the IoP iopart.cls class? I'm using a modified class, supplied by a colleague, which means it *is* necessary to add a bigskip in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the following code

```
\makeatletter

\let\iop@section\section
\def\section{\@ifstar\mod@ssection\mod@section}
\def\mod@ssection#1{\iop@section*{#1}\check@subsection}
\def\mod@section{\@dblarg{\mod@s@ction}}
\def\mod@s@ction[#1]#2{%
  \iop@section[#1]{#2}\ignore@par}
\def\ignore@par{\@ifnextchar\par{\afterassignment\ignore@par\let\next}\check@subsection}
\def\check@subsection{\@ifnextchar\subsection\bigskip{}}

\makeatother
```

But, of course, you can't put `\label` commands after `\section`: for this you have to say

```
\section{A section\label{a-label}}
```

Anyway I believe that the safest method is to check your manuscript for `\subsection` commands directly following a `\section`. Moreover it's not good style, in my opinion, to start directly a subsection after a section title.

Comment: Thanks, that's more complicated than I expected. I think you're right about manually checking through.